# Best Way to Segment Lung Nodules in Matlab

Tags: matlab, image-processing, medical

I am working with images processing in Matlab.  I am trying to segment out only malignant (cancerous) lung nodules. Initially I managed to segment out Lung and all possible nodules.

[image]

I have used following Matlab code:

```
segM = % Segmented Lung 
% Segment nodules
BW = im2bw(segM, 0.55);
```

Now, I want to apply some filter that will filter all benign (noncancerous) nodules. I am looking for solution from long time but I haven’t found any way to continue it.

Here is the segmented Lung:

[image]

**Update:**

Consider the nodule size greater than 3mm is malignant (cancerous). How to calculate the size in mm from the image?

Comment: How do you define a malignant area? Your filtering hinges on this point.

Comment: @Naveh please check the update in question.

Comment: I don't have any background in medical imaging. Do you mean the bright spots are malignant areas? You should know the translation between pixels and length (mm) from the properties of your imaging device.

Comment: @SunilKumar Could you post another `segmented Lung` picture with the lung nodules encircled with some color?

Answer (score 1):

After you run this:

```
% Segment nodules
BW = im2bw(segM, 0.55);
```

You have the nodules in a BW image. Now, to filter out nodules based on the size, you could fit an ellipse to every node and check the major axis length. To do that you could use [regionprops](http://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/regionprops.html) and ask for the `MajorAxisLength`.

Region props will detect all pixel groups (connected components) of your binary image and return information about each group in a struct array.

Try calling it like this:

```
nodules = regionprops(BW, 'MajorAxisLength');
```

It will return a struct array `nodules` where you can access each nodule like this:

```
>> nodules(1)

ans = 

    MajorAxisLength: 4.6188

>> nodules(1).MajorAxisLength

ans =

    4.6188
```

It means the first nodule has a major length of 4.6188 pixels. You can convert that size to millimeters if you know the proportion of your image to the real data. For example, suppose you know that every pixel is equal to 0.4 mm in the real world. Then you just have to multiply that value to `MajorAxisLength` to get the value in mm (and filter the nodules you want).

It would also be useful to know **where** is the nodule you just filtered out. You can ask `regionprops` for more data, such as the `Centroid`, or `BoundingBox`. Perhaps it's also a good idea to take a look at `MinorAxisLength` to avoid detecting "lines" as nodules, or the `Eccentricity` value which tells you "how circle like" a group of pixels is. Take a look at the [documentation](http://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/regionprops.html) for more information.

Also take a look at [this other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11371328/find-out-the-orientation-length-and-radius-of-capped-rectangular-object), it might be useful: