# Shadows around dark places after HDR conversion

Tags: image-processing, gimp, hdr

I have converted photo of local castle to HDR with Luminance HDR on Linux,
but it made shadows around towers of castle.

[image]

I tried dodge & burn tool in gimp, but it does not made smooth edges.. Is there any way, how to easily remove these shadows with gimp? Or any other tool on linux?

Thank you for all your advices..

Comment: I don't have a solution for you using GIMP / Photoshop, but consider transforming the image into HSV and thresholding the hue.  Take a look at this SO post by Rafael Monteiro to help you out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23252114/object-detecting-using-thresholding/23252800#23252800

Answer (score 0):

It looks like an error in placing the images on top of each other.

It might also be a halo resulted by a spatially invariant filtering.